# How would I rewrite the for statements in this function to be more performant?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, optimization, micro-optimization

I have the following function:

```
ColorPalette._processPaletteImageData = function() {
    const paletteImage = this._bmp();
    const source = this._source;
    if (paletteImage) {
        const _colorPicker = (_n) => {
            const pX = source.offsetX + (_n % 8) * 12 + 6;
            const pY = source.offsetY + Math.floor(_n / 8) * 12 + 6;
            return paletteImage.getPixel(pX, pY);
        };
        const _toRgba = (_o) => {return [_o.r, _o.g, _o.b, _o.a]};
        const dataDivisions = source.dataDivisions;
        const splits = (dataDivisions.length - 1);
        let tally = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= splits; i++) {
            this._data[i] = {};
            const colors = (dataDivisions[i] - 1);
            for (let j = 0; j <= colors; j++) {
                const position = tally + j;
                const hex = _colorPicker(position);
                const color = tinycolor(hex);
                const rgba = _toRgba(color.toRgb());
                const score = Utils.computeColorScore(rgba);
                const [colorName, shade] = Utils.hexToColorName(hex).split(DIVISION);
                const inverse = Utils.invertColor(hex, false);
                const complement = color.complement().toHexString();
                this._data[i][colorName] = {
                    "hex": hex,
                    "compliment": complement,
                    "inverse": inverse,
                    "rgba": rgba,
                    "score": score,
                    "shade": shade,
                };
            };
            tally += colors + 1;
        };
    };
};
```

There are two for statements in the aforementioned code:

1. `for (let i = 0; i <= splits; i++)`
2. `for (let j = 0; j <= colors; j++)`

How would I rewrite the function so that the For statements look like:

1. `for (let i = splits; i >= 0; i--)`
2. `for (let j = colors; j >= 0; j--)`

Comment: Is your code currently working as expected? Why do you think that inverting loops order will improve performance?

Comment: Additionally, to help you optimize your code it would be helpful to understand what are you trying to do in the first place.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano: Presumably because, when JITing to x86 machine code, it can compile to `dec reg / jge` instead of `inc reg` / `cmp reg,reg` / `jle`, saving an instruction (and on non-AMD CPUs, a uop for the front-end) and maybe freeing up a register that doesn't need to hold a loop bound.  IDK whether current JS JIT compilers will make nicer loops for less idiomatic source or not.  However, if using `i` or `j` to index memory, slightly worse hardware prefetch for looping in order of decreasing addresses could be a bigger factor.

Comment: (It's obviously not worth making the loop body more complicated just to enable different loop control, that would defeat any tiny savings, so if there's any inter-iteration dependency or reason to loop in forward order, just do that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for pointing that out, it is very interesting. I particularly agree with your latest comment. Especially if we consider modern ECMAScript engines which optimizations are heavily dynamic and not necessarily involve a direct JIT compilation step to machine code. Any code executed inside the loop will most likely impact performance in a much exaggerated way than the loop structure itself.